# Remove parent element from GWT UIBinder

Tags: java, jquery, gwt, gwt-bootstrap

I have a GWT generated accordion element from GWTBootstrap which produces something similar to the html below:

```
<div class="accordion" id="gwt-uid-1234">
    <div class="accordion-group" id="test">
        <div class="accordion-heading">Header1</div>
            ...
    </div>
</div>
```

I wish to replicate this jquery call in order to remove the outer accordion element, without deleting its contents.

```
 $('#test').unwrap();
```

In other words, I want to turn off the Accordion functionality of automatically opening or closing when another accordion is opened, so that all accordions that have been opened remain open.

I wish to do this in an onClick method in my Java class, assigned to a checkbox on screen which a user can use to activate/ deactivate the accordion functionality.

```
public UIPanel() {  
    initWidget(uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this));
    disableCheckbox.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
            if(accordionsDisabled) {
                Window.alert("accordions enabled");
                // IGNORE THIS FOR MEANTIME - REMOVE FUNCT IS PRIORITY 1                
                accordionsDisabled = false;
            } else {
                Window.alert("accordions disabled");
                // remove outer accordion element i.e. $('#test').unwrap();
                contentPanel.getElementById("test").removeParent();
                accordionsDisabled = true;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

I have no success in using the Element or Dom objects in Java (with removeParent methods) Is there any other way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about [gwt-jquery](https://github.com/workingflows/gwt-jquery)? With this you get an interface for jquery and could use the `unwrap` method of `JQueryElement`, to achive exactly the same:

> Remove the parents of the set of matched elements from the DOM leaving
>   the matched elements in their place.

```
public native JQueryElement<T> unwrap();
```

Another interface maintained by GWT Material Design can be found [here](https://github.com/GwtMaterialDesign/gwt-material-jquery). It is based on gwt-jquery. As you can see the `JQueryElement.java` for example is nearly the same. It's also available via Maven.

An alternative **without another library** would be a JSNI (JavaScript Native Interface) method and use the JQuery `unwrap` function like this.

```
private static native void unwrapAccordionGroup() /*-{
      $wnd.jQuery('#test').unwrap()
 }-*/;
```

Comment: I used GWTQuery as you suggested, thanks for the tip! The resulting code looks like this: `GQuery myElement = GQuery.$("#test");
     myElement.unwrap();`